# Vertical CSS Tab while keeping div organized in section

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello I'd like to create a left tab layout:

```
tab1  |   content for selected tab
------|   Here it is tab2
tab2   >  content from other tab is
------|   hidden
tab3  |
------|------------------------------
```

But I would like to keep my organization as follow:

```
 <h3 id="tab1"> tab1 </h3>
 <div class="content"> content for tab1 </div>

 <h3 id="tab2"> tab2 </h3>
 <div class="content"> content for tab2 </div>
 ...
```

Knowing the content is variable.
Is there a known way to achieve this? Or must I change the organisation of the tabs?

---

I tried using float with fixed width but, when the content for tab1 disapear and I show the content for tab2, the block tab2 appear close to tab1:

```
tab1 | tab 2 |
--------------
|  Content for tab 2 
|
|_____________________
tab3 |
```

Thanks!

**edit**

Made clearer I'd like a tab behaviour. I mean, all content should occupy the same space.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can write like this:

```
h3, .content{
    float:left;
}
h3{clear:both;margin-right:20px;}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/LC3Qd/1/

Comment: My concern is I want each content element to occupy the same space. But I am not sure I can achieve this without changing the order of my divs.

Comment: are you sure this is what author wanted? [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LC3Qd/3/) . I think the point is to make the divs  aligned to the top

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just add:

```
h3{ float: left; width: 50px;clear: left;}
.content{float: right;}
```

clearly the easiest way to achieve this layout is to write markup like

```
<div class="float-left">
 <h3>1</h3>
 <h3>2</h3>
</div>
<div class="float-left">
 <div>content1</div>
 <div>content2</div>
</div>
```

but as I understand you would prefer to avoid it. Still i think this is the right approach

Comment: Yes, I know how to make tab by separating each div. But I want to have the ability to display the same content as standard (title then content, then title then content) and as tab (titles on the left, selected tab content on the right). For organization reason, I prefer not to change the order of my divs.